# How to synchronize two methods in a singleton pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have created a database object according to the singleton pattern. The database object contains 2 methods: `connect()` and `update()`.

The update should run multithreaded, meaning that I cannot put `synchronized` in the `update` method signature (I want users to access it simultaneously not one at a time).

My problem is that I want to make sure that 2 scenarios according to this flows:

1. A thread 1 (user1) is the first to create an instance of the DB and thread 2 (user2) is calling the `connect()` and `update()` method to this DB - should not give `NullPointerException` even if by the time that user2 is doing the `update()` the connect from user1 is not done.
2. `update()` should not include `synchronized` (because of the reason I mentioned above).
   Thanks for all the helpers!

SingeltonDB

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    public class SingeltonDB {
        private static DBconnImpl db = null;
        private static SingeltonDB singalDb = null;
          Lock dbLock;

        private SingeltonDB(String username, String password) {
            db = new DBconnImpl();
        }

        public static boolean isOpen() {
            return (db != null);
        }

        public synchronized static SingeltonDB getInstance(String username,
                String password) throws Exception {

            if (db != null) {
                throw (new Exception("The database is  open"));
            } else {
                System.out.println("The database is now open");
                singalDb = new SingeltonDB(username, password);
            }
            db.connect(username, password);
            System.out.println("The database was connected");

            return singalDb;
        }

        public synchronized static SingeltonDB getInstance() throws Exception {
            if (db == null) {
                throw (new Exception("The database is not open"));
            }

            return singalDb;
        }

        public void create(String tableName) throws Exception {
            dbLock = new ReentrantLock();
            dbLock.lock();
            db.create(tableName);
            dbLock.unlock();
        }

        public  User query(String tableName, int rowID) throws Exception {
            if (db == null) {
                System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
                return null;
            }
            return (db.query(tableName, rowID));
        }

        public  void update(String tableName, User user) throws Exception {
            if (db == null) {
                System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
                return;
            }
            db.update(tableName, user);
        }

    }
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Creator cr= new Creator(new UserContorller());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(cr);
        t1.start();
        Producer pr = new Producer(new UserContorller());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(pr);
        t2.start();

        /*
         * Consumer cn = new Consumer(new UserContorller()); Thread t2 = new
         * Thread(cn); t2.start();
         */
    }
}

class Creator implements Runnable {
    UserContorller uc;

    public Creator(UserContorller uc) {
        this.uc = uc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            uc = new UserContorller("MyAccount", "123");
            uc.createTable("table1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    UserContorller uc;

    public Producer(UserContorller uc) {
        this.uc = uc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                uc.saveUser("table1", i, "User", i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    UserContorller uc;

    public Consumer(UserContorller uc) {
        this.uc = uc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(uc.getUser("table1", i));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is in the update method please show the code

Comment: without any more information, I can only assume your database is an array of strings held in the singleton.  That will do for now anyway.  There is no way for two clients to update the same string, at the same time, that makes sense.  There certainly isn't a way for two clients to add strings to the vector at the same time.  Something somewhere MUST be blocking.

Comment: `connect()` and `update()` should not belong to the same class.  the connect() method should return a new Connection object, and update() should be something that you do to the connection.  For more information, read about "hidden temporal couplings" in http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: The post below was written in the perspective of both users using the same credentials (hidden from them) to connect to the database. If users employ different credentials, the idea of a singleton db object is purposeless, each user should have their own connection object, and of course then connection details are passed on from the user to the Db via whatever represents the user in the program (here the thread instances apparently).*

The main issue in the implementation you provided is that the `getinstance` method requires its caller to know the connection details, or assume that the connection has already been done. But neither threads could nor should know *in advance* if the Db has been opened already -- and design wise it's a mistake to hand them the responsibility of explicitely opening it. These threads are work threads, they shouldn't be concerned about Db configuration details.

The only sane way to handle this situation is to have these configuration parameters held by the Db object directly, or better yet another object in charge of providing it (it's the [*factory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern).

However, if you want first your code to work with minimal changes, get rid of the parameter less `getinstance` method, have any thread requiring the Db object to use the remaining variant of that method, passing along the correct parameters, and change it to return the instance if it exists, or create it otherwise, without raising an exception. I believe that it's what @Dima has been trying to explain in his answer.

Comment: Thanks! how do you recommend I use the factory pattern here? I have 2 cases: user connect for the first time with name and pass (then we need to connect()), and user connect without name and pass after he knows datavase is opened (no need to connect()).

Comment: Thanks... just to be clear- you are saying that since the singelton pattern is ment to give an instance of a shared object and *does not requeired the users of the singelton* to acutally know if they are the first to create this object or they are given an existing object that was already created - I should not try to sperate the getInstance() method and the thread should be "dumb" in terms of not knowning if they are creating or just reciving a object that was instantiated?
Thansk!

Comment: I am indeed saying that as far as they are concerned, threads should not know that the object they are requesting has been constructed just now or before. `GetInstance` (and the *singleton* pattern) does the book-keeping for them.

Answer (score 1):

Connect once, when creating the singleton (in the constructor, perhaps). 
Have a **synchronized** static method (`getInstance` or something), that checks if an instance exists, creates **and** connects as necessary, and returns the instance. By following this protocol, you ensure that threads always get a connected Db object ready to be used.

The users will call that method to get the singleton instance, and call `update` or whatever they want on it, it does not need to be synchronized.

Comment: I added a code above. the problem is that the update method is actually depends on the DB static constructor - meaning if thread1 has not finish with the constructor or the getInstance() method (even though it was the first thread to be executed) then thread 2 will get a nullpointerexception. so I need to make sure the if the constractor is called - the update will wait for it to finish (but the update() will still run withought synchronized)

Comment: `update` is an instance method. To call an instance method, you need an instance to call it on, right? Until constructor has finished, the instance does not exist. Therefore nobody can call `update` before constructor is finished. Think about it.